# Spring Boot multi-context application.properties issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot multi-context problem with **current directory** `application.properties`

In Spring Boot documentation [Application Property Files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)

> 1. A /config subdirectory of the current directory
> 2. The current directory
> 3. A classpath /config package
> 4. The classpath root

application structure:

```
+plugin
    +src
        +main
          +java
            +my/package/PluginContext.java
    +resources/application.properties
+client
    +src
        +main
          +java
            +my/package/ClientBean.java
    +resources/application.properties
+runner
    +src
        +main
          +java
            +my/package/RunnerContext.java
    +resources/application.properties
```

dependency structure:

```
runner <- client <- plugin
```

**RunnerContext** run own `ApplicationContext` and autowire **ClientBean** then **ClientBean** run **Plugin** `ApplicationContext`

`application.properties` not visible in **PluginContext** from `plugin` and `client` modules, only from `runner` because it is **root**, but where the **current directory** ? what does this mean **current directory** ?

Is it possible to include `application.properties` to **PluginContext** from own `plugin` module, without additional configurations (external via `@PropertySource` or `spring.config.location`) ?

Comment: you can give specific path as @propertysource(file:path)

Comment: please read the last line in my question :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is multi-module with different config.

---

First, We know using :

    `spring.profile.active=[suffix]`

This configuration can define to active other config properties files, like using `spring.profile.active=dev` is using config file `application.xml` and  `application-dev.properties` in your context.

---

There is a situation: if you dependency a module, you also dependency the config properties. What you need to do is Override it.

Add one file `application.properties` in your `plugin` project or module, Override the configuration you want.
If you want to have different deploy environment with different config file, just add another config file like `application-online.properties` in `plugin` project. Then active this config file, switch active config whenever you want, all good.

---

By the way, I suggest you using `yml` config file. Easier, lighter, effective with point out.